# What is the cause of my BSOD?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, amd-radeon, memory-management, bluescreenview

Since yesterday, I got different BSOD on my Windows 7 PC. I can't figure out the exact cause of it. You can see all the BSOD codes that I got below. A few days ago, I tried to update my BIOS, but since I rolled back the BIOS upgrade (I'm not sure if it has something to do with the crashes).

[image]

**EDIT#1:** 
Here, you can see the results (*osronline.pdf & osronline(2).pdf*) from osronline for 2 dump files. You can also see the first 6 rows of the BlueScreenView :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s9syouigf59gu72/AABLckikiaQOIIUep0sEFX8ja?dl=0

Comment: BlueScreenViewer is not helpful in a case like this.  You should use windbg to determine the cause.

Comment: just a quick suggestion which is try taking out your RAM stick/s and putting them back in even in slots A2 and B2 or 3 and 4 depending on your motherboard brand. I have had lots of BSOD fixes that came down to RAM issues such as a faulty RAM stick, bad settings and timings or even a faulty dimm slot? This might and proberly not help much but its worth going back to the basics in a lot of cases that I have experienced so good luck and hope this helps.

Comment: I had similar BSODs lately, and in my case it turned out to be one of the hard disks that was failing. I would initially look at RAM as the culprit, but it could be worth also checking the disks.

Comment: Stop 116 and 10e can be related to graphics driver issues. Try removing the graphics card driver completely and then download/install an updated version. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557238(v=vs.85).aspx and: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557263(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You could try sending a few to http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze and link the results.

Comment: _Do I need to do so for both Intel HD Graphics 4000 and AMD Radeon 7600M Series?_ I removed the AMD Radeon driver and I installed it back (however, I don't think that I downloaded an updated version since this product has been moved to a legacy support model). Now, in my Device Manager, I got the following error under my driver: *Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)* Thanks for helping !

Comment: @EMK: Here are the results: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouuoqt5wcz1r2hm/csronline.pdf?dl=0

Comment: If you use BlueScreenView, at least enlarge the window so all columns are visible.

Comment: @Benjamin, it would be better to be able to expand all the info on the page, which I can't do with the pdf. "Loaded module list", etc...

Comment: we can't debug he 0x116 BSODs, MS never includes te required debug info into their debug symbols. Use [DDU](http://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=5) to remove the GPU drivers and reinstall the latest drivers.

Comment: @EMK: You should now be able to see the full results from osronline for 2 dump files (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s9syouigf59gu72/AABLckikiaQOIIUep0sEFX8ja?dl=0)

Comment: @DanielB: You're right. I've linked a file with the full description of the first 6 rows of the BlueScreenView.

Comment: @Benjamin Can you upload dump files (.dmp, not PDF) so I can take a look at them?

Comment: @KevinD: Alright, you should see the .dmp files now

Answer (score 1):

I found from your DUMP file is that this BSOD error was caused by dxgmms1.sys. It appears an Windows Update on your Windows 7.

> dxgmms1.sys - DirectX Graphics MMS - Windows Update

[image]

Besides, in another DUMP file, it was caused by atikmpag.sys.

> atikmpag.sys - ATI Video driver (remove the Catalyst Control Center and only install the Display Driver)

[image]

I would recommend uninstall any Windows updates that you have installed lately before getting this BSOD error. Besides, uninstall the driver of your graphics card and download & install the latest version of it.